# Eclipse C++ default "Hello World" errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, default

This is my first post here, so sorry if it's a little bit bad :I but I have a problem. When I tried to make a Hello World C++ project in Eclipse (first time trying c++) I tried to build the project and run it, but it said that there are errors.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

And also here is a screenshot of the errors:

[image]

I tried looking but couldn't find a solution, so sorry if I look stupid for being a total noob :\ All and any help is appreciated. :) Thanks!

Comment: you should mention your Eclipse version, what your C compiler is and where it locates

Comment: The C++ code you posted should compile.  So something may not be set up right with Eclipse, causing problems with resolving `std`.  The Eclipse community has some suggestions that could resolve the errors: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/285005/

Comment: This is on Windows? What kind of compiler do you have installed and where? Is it in path?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good to me. I think you didn't setup C++ in Eclipse correctly.

Follow the step-by-step setup [here](http://www.fayewilliams.com/2011/06/28/creating-your-first-c-program-in-eclipse/). You should be able to work it out after correct setup.

[image]

Comment: You need a return type for `main`. And there shouldn't be a  ".h" at the end of `iostream`.

Comment: @AlanStokes Fixed. Sorry for my previous misunderstanding.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I followed everything exactly as it was in the post you linked, and it is exactly the same thing as what happened before.

Comment: @vinsterhf Sounds weird to me. Can you run Java code successfully in Eclipse?

Comment: Just going to say, your advice is completely unhelpful. The 'setup' for Eclipse in that link is install it, make a new project and run it. There is no additional steps to take that might fix OP's problems. There is no way that OP can have gotten to the point they are at now unless they followed the steps in that guide. Now I've come across this after having the same issue this answer has done nothing towards solving it.